# Online resource to troubleshoot issues with my personal project

Tags: resource-request

I am currently working on my own quantum conventional neural network as a project to enhance my learning. However, I have reached a dead end where my code was successfully working, but after attempting to optimize it, it no longer functions correctly.

I was wondering what resources are available (both paid and non-paid) where I can seek assistance in correcting or troubleshooting my code.

Since this is a side project and I am currently studying a different major at university, I don't have anyone there whom I can ask for help.

Could you please provide me with some recommendations for getting help?

Comment: Could you please provide the code? It can help others to find proper answer to your issue.